# Joining two tables, two columns while displaying multiple rows as a single row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

The tables are setup as follows:

```
fighters:

fighterid
firstname
lastname
etc
etc

matches:

matchid
fighteroneid (fighterid FK)
fightertwoid (fighterid FK)
etc
etc
```

I want to join both the fighteroneid and fightertwoid to the fighterid where they have the same matchid (I'm pretty sure I've got this part figured out), but where I'm failing is at attempting to display it in a listbox as follows:

```
firstname lastname vs firstname lastname
```

I can use COALESCE to display the fighteroneid and fightertwoid as 1 vs 2 for instance, but how do I instead link to the firstname and lastname of each fighter given those ID's?

Thanks in advance,

Spence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
          f1.firstname
        , f1.lastname
        , f2.firstname
        , f2.lastname
    FROM matches AS m
        INNER JOIN fighters AS f1
            ON f1.fighterid = m.fighteroneid
        INNER JOIN fighters AS f2
            ON f2.fighterid = m.fightertwoid
```

Comment: By way of explanation, the technique being used here is a variant of a self-join, where the same table is joined twice with different aliases to a common table.